# How to use this word "metamorphose"

Tags: word-usage

The word "**metamorphoses**"[n] is defined according to [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/metamorphosis) dictionary as

> a process in which something changes completely into something very
>   different. [**SYN** *transformation*]

Another definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metamorphosis)

> change of physical form, structure, or substance especially by
>   supernatural means

Even though the word in the aforementioned dictionary has another definition, but it seems to me the meaning of this word is strictly related to the biological morph. **My question** is is it feasible to use this word interchangeably with transform?  For example, can I say

> Some students have *metamorphosed* their major from mathematics to
>   engineering.

Comment: Of course you *can* say it.  Should you say it?  That entirely depends on what you're trying to convey.  Are you trying to sound eccentric?

Comment: @Juhasz, *Are you trying to sound **eccentric**?* Of course not, but I'm trying to make sure not to misuse the meaning of the word if I write an essay since English  is not my native tongue. I don't want to be aberrant.

Comment: @Juhasz - "CroCo" seems pretty round to me.  (Well-centered, I can't say.)

Comment: Sorry, CroCo.  I opted for being snarky instead of being clear.  That's always a mistake here.  What I meant was the meaning will probably be clear, but it's a pretty unusual usage. If you really want to draw attention to the phrase, or if you really mean to suggest that changing your major from math to engineering is "an abrupt or startling change induced by or as if by magic or a supernatural power" as *Merriam-Webster* puts it, then it may be appropriate.  If you're just looking for a synonym for *change*, there are better options.

Comment: It is awkward to say you metamorphosed your major.  It would  be better to say: "after taking  a course in "Civil Engineering and Environmental Problems" I metamorphosed from a mathematician to an embryonic environmental engineer."

Comment: Since English is not your native language, I'll point out that it's an unusual word, and you'd probably be better off using a plainer word like "change," which will not confuse anyone.

Comment: Metamorphose carries a connotation of more than a simple choice - it implies that something became something new and different, a categorical change. A lemonade stand might change into an iced tea stand, or it could metamorphose into a beverage distribution company.

Comment: You can "change your train" as in go from one train to another, or "change your train" as in modify the train that you own. "metamorphose" only has the latter meaning, but in talking of "change your course" you mean the former meaning.

Comment: @Stuart F is quite right. 'Change' can mean 'switch', so you can 'change / switch' courses. But 'change' also means 'effect alterations in', with synonyms 'alter'/'transform'/'metamorphose'/'transmogrify', and these are completely at odds with the 'switch' sense. So neither 'metamorphose' nor 'transform' is correct in 'Some students have V-ed their major from mathematics to engineering'.

Comment: @MikeHarris, *Since English is not your native language*, it has nothing to do with that. If I know the meaning of this word firmly, then utilizing the word will be a matter of eloquence.

Comment: @ab2ReinstateMonicaNow "*It is awkward to say you metamorphosed your major. It would be better to say*", it is merely an example and I wouldn't use it in this sentence.